# Determining if a pack is empty or not

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming

Can someone explain why this static assertion is false?  How to redefine `is_empty` so that it works the way I want it to (without changing the syntax)?  A type that is not a pack I want to evaluate to false by default (e.g. `is_empty<int>::value` shall be false).

```
#include <type_traits>
template <typename Pack> struct is_empty : std::false_type {};

template <typename T, template <T...> class Z, T... Is>
struct is_empty<Z<Is...>> : std::true_type {};

template <typename T, template <T...> class Z, T First, T... Rest>
struct is_empty<Z<First, Rest...>> : std::false_type {};

template <int...> struct Z;

int main() {
    static_assert(is_empty<Z<>>::value);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the type `T` contained in `Z` can't be deduced.

Works if you explicit it and I don't know how to avoid to explicit.

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename...>
struct is_empty : std::false_type
 { };

template <typename T, template <T...> class Z, T... Is>
struct is_empty<T, Z<Is...>> : std::true_type
 { };

template <typename T, template <T...> class Z, T First, T... Rest>
struct is_empty<T, Z<First, Rest...>> : std::false_type
 { };

template <int...> struct Z;

int main() {
    static_assert(is_empty<int, Z<>>::value, "!");
}
```

**-- EDIT --**

Works if your `Z` require a first argument type (in the way of `std::integer_sequence`); in this way the deduction works

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename>
struct is_empty : std::false_type
 { };

template <typename T, template <typename U, U...> class Z, T... Is>
struct is_empty<Z<T, Is...>>
   : std::integral_constant<bool, sizeof...(Is) == 0U>
 { };

template <typename T, T ...>
struct X
 { };

template <int ... Is>
using Y = X<int>;

int main ()
 {
   static_assert(is_empty<X<int>>::value, "!");
   static_assert(is_empty<Y<>>::value, "!");
 }
```

**-- EDIT 2 --**

In C++17 works with `auto`

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename Pack>
struct is_empty : std::false_type
 { };

template <template <auto...> class Z, auto... Is>
struct is_empty<Z<Is...>> : std::bool_constant<sizeof...(Is) == 0U>
 { };

template <int...>
struct X;

int main()
 {
   static_assert( true  == is_empty<X<>>::value );
   static_assert( false == is_empty<X<1>>::value );
   static_assert( false == is_empty<int>::value );
 }
```

Comment: Yes, that was my alternate solution, which I need to avoid.  So there's no way to maintain my syntax?

Comment: @prestokeys - as far I know, no. But I'm not an expert and someone better than me can find a solution. Maybe with C++17 should be possible (but you tagged C++11) but I'm failing also with it.

Comment: @prestokeys - answer a little improved but not exactly what you asked

Comment: @prestokeys - solved for C++17; see "edit 2" (ps: I love "`auto`")

Comment: Yes, and while we are using C++17, `std::bool_constant` can be used instead of `std::integral_constant<bool,`  Answer accepted.

Comment: I would love to use this -- but it does not compile for me with clang 12. https://godbolt.org/z/ME49fee6j

<source>:7:21: error: 'auto' parameter not permitted in this context
    7 | template <template <auto...> class Z, auto... Is>

Comment: @JoeSteele - I don't know the default C++ version for clang++ 12 but seems it's lower than C++17. And `template <auto...>` is available only starting from C++17. Solution: compile C++17 (that is: add `--std c++17` in compiler arguments)

Comment: @max66 that's good advice but unfortunately the first thing I checked. I did not try c++2a (although that would not actually help me).

Comment: @JoeSteele - sorry but ... if you follow your [godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/z/ME49fee6j) and you add "`--std c++17`" in the "compiler option" sections (on the right of the red failure signs), your code compile correctly.

Comment: No need for apologies! I learned something new today. I did not realize you needed to set the options in multiple places. With that it did indeed work.

Answer (score 19):

Why do you do that?

You can do `sizeof...(args)` to determine the length of the parameter pack.. If it is 0, then it is empty:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename... Args>
void func(Args... args)
{
    std::cout<<(sizeof...(args));
}

int main() {

    func(1, 2, 3);
    func();
    func(1);
    func(1, 2);
    func(1, 2, 3, 4);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @ Brandon  I need it evaluated at compile-time.  But you did give me some ideas.

Comment: What makes you think that `sizeof...` is not evalated at compile time? It is, just like plain `sizeof`. So, you could then create your traits templates in a simpler way, using that.

Comment: @prestokeys `sizeof...` is compile time. You can use it in `static_assert` or other templates. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack#The_sizeof..._operator

Comment: Exactly..+1. When I first saw the post, I immediately thought of `sizeof...`, but then I was hesitant to post this, was under impression that OP might have already thought about it and he must be a template ninja !